# Agrupar por intervalo de dias usando Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, range

Como posso usar agrupamento com intervalos com Linq?

```
var dados = new[] {
    new { Id = 0, dias=100, preco= 25,  Nome="etc"},
    new { Id = 1, dias=40,  preco= 50,  Nome="etc1"},
    new { Id = 2, dias=50,  preco= 55,  Nome="etc2"},
    new { Id = 3, dias=80,  preco= 70,  Nome="etc3"},
    new { Id = 4, dias=150, preco= 90,  Nome="etc4"},
    new { Id = 5, dias=420, preco= 100, Nome="etc5"},
    new { Id = 6, dias=122, preco= 500, Nome="etc6"},
};
```

Usando o Linq como posso retornar uma lista com a soma dos preços agrupando por um intervalo de dias.

> 31 a 60;
>
> 61 a 90;
>
> 91 a 120;
>
> 121 a 150;
>
> e maior que 150;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utlizar o group by para juntar todos pelo intervalo e depois transformar em um dicionario pegando a chave do grupo como a Key e a soma do preco como Value

```
var dic=dados.OrderBy(x=>x.dias).GroupBy(x =>
        {
            if (x.dias > 30 && x.dias < 60)
                return "31 a 60";
            if (x.dias > 60 && x.dias < 90)
                return "61 a 90";
            if (x.dias > 90 && x.dias < 120)
                return "91 a 120";
            if(x.dias > 120 && x.dias < 150)
                return "121 a 150";

            return "maior que 150";
        }).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Sum(y => y.preco));
```

Veja funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N75oWX)

Comment: Só faltou para as condições  está <= ao invés de <;
Substituí ToDictionary por Select.
Mas já ajudou bastante

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize a sua lista de limites superiores, utilizando-a no [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var limites = new[] {60, 90, 120, 150, 420};

var grupos = dados.GroupBy(dado => limites.First(limite => limite >= dado.dias))
                  .Select(grupo => new { Soma = grupo.Select(g => g.preco).Sum() });
```

Exemplo funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0W1pYI).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei como base a resposta do [Tiago S](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/44289/tiago-s) e ficou como eu desejo, vide resposta no link
[DotNetFiddle Resposta](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CFHNnA)